# How do I prevent session hijacking?

Tags: php, session, pdo

I'm trying to make a loginscript that is protected against session hijacking. My question is : How do i do this? i don't really understand how i can do this in a secure way. currently i have this code.

```
if (!empty($_POST["naam"]) && !empty($_POST["wachtwoord"]))
{
    $naam = $_POST["naam"];
    $wachtwoord = $_POST["wachtwoord"];
    $salt = "boterhammetkaas";
    $wachtwoord = sha1($wachtwoord.$salt);
    $query =$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM opdracht4 WHERE naam = :naam and wachtwoord = :wachtwoord");
    $query->bindParam(':naam', $naam, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':wachtwoord', $wachtwoord, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $rij = $query->rowCount();
    if($rij == 1) 
    {
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $status = $result->status;
    //setcookie("TestCookie", $status, time()+3600);
    //setcookie("ip", $ip, time()+3600);
    $_SESSION['status']= $status;
    $_SESSION['naam']= $naam;
    }
    else 
    {
       $antwoord = 'Deze gegevens zijn niet bekend';
    }

 if (!empty($_SESSION["status"]))
        {
            if ($_SESSION["status"] == 1)
            {
                include 'beheerder4.php';
                $page = 'overzicht';
            }
            if ($_SESSION["status"] == 2)
            {
                include 'projectleider4.php';
                $page = 'overzicht';
            }
            if ($_SESSION["status"] == 3)
            {
                include 'gebruiker4.php';
                $page = 'overzicht';
            }
        }
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: Does `wachtwoord` mean `password`?

Comment: yes sorry i wrote it in dutch.

Comment: Have you looked into SSL encryption on your server? If you're doing this over plain http then that would be the first place to start.

Comment: I hope you are going to change your salt later on because it isn't smart to post it online if you don't. I would really like a cheese sandwich now :)

Comment: haha it will never be used online don't worry pure practise :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most session hijacking attempts can be prevented simply by using proper SSL/TLS encryption to your server, and saving your cookies as secure (https-only - 6th parameter to `setcookie`).

This will stop man-in-the-middle attacks and browser extensions like firesheep from sniffing packets to get this information.

Nothing will stop someone from physical access to the computer. It's just not possible, nor is it worth protecting from (most people have much more on their computer that they'd care to lose or have in the hands of someone else than their social networking accounts).